# SQL Issue with Group By's . Choose a PK based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display only the most recent appointmentId by CustomerId . I know im doing the query all wrong but how can i achieve the desired result

```
SELECT TEMP.AppointmentId,TEMP.AppointmentDateTime,TEMP.PatientId,MAX(TEMP.AppointmentDateTime)
       
FROM
(SELECT 
        Appointment.Id AS AppointmentId,
        Appointment.DateTime AS AppointmentDateTime,
        Customer.Id AS CustomerId
        
          

FROM Customer
    
        INNER JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.CustomerId = Customer.Id
        INNER JOIN CustomerUser ON CustomerUser.CustomerId = Customer.Id
        
        
WHERE Appointment.UpdatedAt >= @StartDate AND Appointment.UpdatedAt <= @EndDate 
    AND Appointment.Is_Active = 1
    AND Customer.Is_Active = 1
    AND CustomerUser.Is_Active = 1 
    

) AS TEMP
    
GROUP BY TEMP.AppointmentId,TEMP.AppointmentDateTime,TEMP.CustomerId
```

This is the result set that i have

```
AppointmentId   AppointmentDateTime         CustomerId

8909            2020-12-24 13:39:00     98
8931            2020-12-18 10:30:00     26
8932            2020-12-17 14:30:00     26
8933            2020-11-06 15:30:00     26
8934            2020-12-30 17:31:00     153
8936            2020-12-21 11:06:00     180
8938            2020-12-25 23:00:00     153
8943            2020-12-21 17:45:00     188
9046            2020-12-30 13:49:00     98
```

But this is the **Expected result**

```
AppointmentId   AppointmentDateTime         CustomerId


8931            2020-12-18 10:30:00     26
8934            2020-12-30 17:31:00     153
8936            2020-12-21 11:06:00     180
8943            2020-12-21 17:45:00     188
9046            2020-12-30 13:49:00     98
```

Comment: Looking at your query I am guessing you're using SQL server?
Your query looks good. I am confused by what you're trying to display? It looks like what's causing you duplicate values is the appointment id? It looks like you want also to find the max appointment id?
Either way you are looking for something which you havent mentioned either it be 1 appointment id? or 1 customer id?

Comment: Your query does not match your stated goal - be careful what you assume. First, you seek "most recent appointmentId". ID generally has no direct relationship to time. I might make an appointment now for 6 months later. At some later date, I might make another appointment that occurs before the 6 month one. And I might change an older appointment to push it out after a later one. Perhaps not likely in your business - but you need to think about "possible" not just "usual". You also filter the rows considered - another potential problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to display only the most recent appointmentId of a Patient based on the AppointmentDateTime.

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from Appointment a
where a.AppointmentDateTime = (select max(a2 AppointmentDateTime)
                               from Appointment a2
                               where a2.customerid = a.customerid
                              );
```

Your query is considerably more complicated than this, including tables and conditions not explained in the question.  However, this answers the question that you have asked.

Comment: well this is indeed much more simplified it works but i still need to perform this join : INNER JOIN CustomerUser ON CustomerUser.CustomerId = Customer.Id. This will have to go inside the sub-query right?

Comment: @JohnnyJoe . . . It depends.  If you need columns in the outer query, then this goes in the outer query.

Comment: i joined in the outer query first of all, but it happens that i am having repeated results of AppointmentID's, maybe if i group by this attribute it will solve the problem?  select a.*
from Customer 
INNER JOIN Appointment a ON a.CustomerId = Customer.Id
INNER JOIN CustomerUser ON CustomerUser.CustomerId = Customer.Id
where a.AppointmentDateTime = (select max(a2 AppointmentDateTime)
                               from Appointment a2
                               where a2.customerid = a.customerid
                              );

Answer (score 0):

You made it too complicated. You only need one query and you need to remove your aggregated field from the group by statement.

```
SELECT 
        MAX(Appointment.Id) AS MaxAppointmentId,
        MAX(Appointment.DateTime) AS AppointmentDateTime,
        Customer.Id AS CustomerId
FROM Customer
        INNER JOIN Appointment ON Appointment.CustomerId = Customer.Id
        INNER JOIN CustomerUser ON CustomerUser.CustomerId = Customer.Id
WHERE Appointment.UpdatedAt >= @StartDate AND Appointment.UpdatedAt <= @EndDate 
    AND Appointment.Is_Active = 1
    AND Customer.Is_Active = 1
    AND CustomerUser.Is_Active = 1 
GROUP BY Customer.Id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input but that doesn't solve my problem. I still have the same  output, listing all the AppointmentID's for the same CustomerId . i only want to display only the most recent appointmentId by CustomerId

Comment: I changed the query based on your needs. Now you have both the max appointment id and the max appointment date by the customer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want.

```
select *
from 
( select *, row_number() over (partition by customerid order by AppointmentDateTime desc) as rn
from expandtable ) as t
where rn = 1
```